# How to pull DCM reports with more than 10000 rows into google sheets using apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, double-click-advertising

I'm triyng to get a full report from DCM via Google apps scripts, to insert it in a spreadsheet.
This code works fine, except I cannot pull reports with more than 10K rows.

```
function DCMdownload() {

  var reportId = 111825394
  var profileId = 2406185; 
  var httpOptions = {'headers': {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + 
ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};       
  var additionalParameters = {'synchronous': 'true'};

  //corro el reporte e identifico el file ID
  var ReportFile = DoubleClickCampaigns.Reports.run(profileId, reportId, 
additionalParameters);
  var ReportFileID = (ReportFile.id);

  //obtengo el csv y lo parseo
  var newReportFile = DoubleClickCampaigns.Files.get(reportId, 
ReportFileID);
  if(newReportFile.urls) {var httpOptions = {'headers': {'Authorization': 
'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};
  var csvContent = UrlFetchApp.fetch(newReportFile.urls.apiUrl, 
httpOptions).getContentText();
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csvContent);

  //pego la data en la sheet que esté activa 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, 
csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);

  //eliminar primeras filas y fila de total
  var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow()
  sheet.deleteRows(1, 11);
  var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow()
  sheet.deleteRows(lastrow);

}
}
```

This works ok with reports with less than 10.000 rows, as you can add them to drive with a button in the DCM interface. If it has more than 10k rows, this option is disabled. It seems that you cannot import it neither in google sheets.

Any work around to solve this?

Cross-posted to SOes

- [Cómo insertar reportes de DCM de más de 10000 filas en google sheets con apps scripts?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/123056)

Comment: What error do you get? How many cells are you importing? How many cells will have your spreadsheet after the import?

Answer (score 0):

You have this in you code:

```
var csvContent = UrlFetchApp.fetch(newReportFile.urls.apiUrl, 
httpOptions).getContentText();
```

There is a rate limit set on fetch calls as I remember it is 10 mb per call and [100 mb per day.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) Workarounds could involve using some kind of limit in your request and then calling again to get the next part of the data. This is okay as long as they don't go above the 100 mb for that day. From my limited experience if the Sheet is going to be 10,000 + rows I would consider using something else for analysis. How about Google's Data Studio? That can pull data from multiple source types?